# press s for skip mounting and m for manual

Tags: mount, fstab

I've installed 3 vm's on virtual manager, I've successfully mounted a file system(mapped) with the host but when I try to mount the file system with the second vm and reboot it's giving me the error as above. I've tried `nobootwait` in `/etc/fstab` it's not helping and file system is not mounting.

My contents of `/etc/fstab` on second vm:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=43ac7681-6e1c-499f-8059-f5b8f3082916 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/vda5 during installation
UUID=2f00440c-d28c-41ba-8b8a-75e816dea4a6,nobootwait none            swap    sw              0       0
g2   /mnt    9p  trans=virtio,version=9p2000.u,rw    0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove nobootwait from the following line

```
UUID=2f00440c-d28c-41ba-8b8a-75e816dea4a6,nobootwait none            swap    sw              0       0
```

also remove the line

```
g2   /mnt    9p  trans=virtio,version=9p2000.u,rw    0   0
```

add the following line to the file `/etc/rc.local`

```
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,rw g2 /mnt
```

This will execute this command when you start the ubuntu vm and mount the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your fstab. The line

```
UUID=2f00440c-d28c-41ba-8b8a-75e816dea4a6,nobootwait none  swap    sw           0       0
```

should be

```
UUID=2f00440c-d28c-41ba-8b8a-75e816dea4a6 none            swap    sw            0       0
```

with a space after the disk ID. If you want to add the nobootwait option, it should go after the `sw`:

```
UUID=2f00440c-d28c-41ba-8b8a-75e816dea4a6 none            swap    sw,nobootwait 0       0
```

Comment: I corrected  fstab as u said but it's giving me the same error while booting. File systen is not mounted!
I used this to mount first vm
guest# mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,rw share /mnt

I used this to mount second vm
guest# mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.U,rw g2 /mnt
I've changed as above in fstab